# How do booktabs rule commands handle empty argument?

Tags: rules, multicolumn, booktabs

I would like to know how `booktabs` rule commands handle empty argument.

As an example the following example doesn't compile (with `LuaLatex`):

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
  \toprule{}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{foobar}\\
  \bottomrule{}
\end{tabular}
```

with the following error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.9   \multicolumn{1}{c}{foobar}
                              \\
```

While the following example compiles without any error:

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
  \toprule% <----- No braces here
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{foobar}\\
  \bottomrule{}
\end{tabular}
```

---

Edit:

The MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    \toprule{}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{foobar}\\ 
    \bottomrule{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks for the answer.

---

Useless details:

This is the only MWE that I took time to do, but the error appears in other cases, sometimes on doubled `midrule`.
As a developer, I like to make explicit what is the argument even if it is none, and thus the standard `booktabs` construction (without braces) doesn't  please me.

Comment: `\toprule` does not have a mandatory argument, so the `{}` behind is an empty group and begins the first column of the next row. `\multicolumn` can only be used before the column has been started. BTW: Your example is not a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), because a MWE has `\documentclass`, loading of all packages needed for the problem, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Adding an empty argument when there's none is good perhaps in C, but not in TeX. An empty group can be handy, at times; in other situations it can be wrong. You've found one, `$3\sim{}-3$` is another (try it with and without `{}`).

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for the brief answer. Actually, I prepared a MWE but I forgot to post it... Sorry 

Comment: @AlexisBRENON the comparison with functions in programming languages is spurious really:  consider `\newcommand\two{2}`  this is no more analogous to a a C function than a C variable and after two=2 you can't use two() in C either and in programming languages with functions normally the `()` is required to recognise the preceding token as a function, but tex is a macro language it doesn't have functions and (like the C pre-processor macro language) parameterless macros do not take arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to stretch LaTeX's syntax.

A macro without arguments does *not* want `{}` after it. After a parameterless macro this is an empty group (and an unexpandable list of tokens), which can be handy in situations such as

```
\LaTeX{} is great
```

but would be a disaster in

```
$a \sim{} -b$
```

It's a disaster also after `\toprule`, `\midrule` and even `\bottomrule` because it makes an additional table row. Witness the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tabular}{l}\toprule a\\\bottomrule\end{tabular}}
\fbox{\begin{tabular}{l}\toprule{} a\\\bottomrule{}\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So maybe this doesn't please you, but adding `{}` displeases TeX. Who wins? `;-)`

Comment: As you stated, adding empty argument is good in programming languages like C. Here, this just make LaTeX a little bit inconsistent, as some macros allow them and others don't. But I don't have the choice `;-)`

Comment: @AlexisBRENON It's a different paradigm. I don't understand the need for `{}`: multiple arguments require multiple brace sets; if `\macro` has two arguments, you can't pass them as `\macro{a,b}`, but only as `\macro{a}{b}`.